# When you generate the signed apk Firebase Database does not work correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app works perfectly when I run on mobile directly through Android Studio (usb debugging). When I register in the app, it creates the user account in Firebase Authentication (id, name, email) and saves
the user data in Firebase Realtime Database (id, name, email, region). Then the app's main screen opens and in the main screen's onCreat, I save the user's token in the database. The app gives no errors.

[image]

The problem:

But when I generate the signed apk and install it on my phone, by doing the same process, that is, making the registration of
a user, the registration is done but saves the node names with strange names, the data is saved more instead of for example being:

name: john

It is created:

b: john

[image]

After that, it opens the main app screen with the logged in user and the crasha app, as null object errors happen as it cannot find the right named values in the Database. The only data that is saved with the node name correctly is the token, as the token is only saved to the main screen's onCreat when it opens. That makes no sense...

I do not know what may be causing this, when I run the app by debugging everything works perfectly, just generate the signed apk that happens and the app is impossible to use.

NOTE: I tried to generate with the Android App Bundle instead of generating the APK, but it does not solve. The app is on Google Play as Alpha, I already added the two SHA-1 codes that appear on the Google Play console under "Signature" in the Firebase project, and put the google-services file in the project, it didn't resolve either. I do not know what to do. Could this have anything to do with ProGuard?

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA, the question you're referring to says it doesn't work. In this case, it works with distorted field names. It's proguard that obfuscates classes so names appear distorted. See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57937362/5636313

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA, appreciate it.