# When I generate the signed apk, save the wrong data to Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I run the usb debugging app, it saves the data correctly when I register the user:

[image]

But when I generate the signed apk, doing the same process saves it this way in Firebase Database:

[image]

What is happening? (i use android studio)

Comment: Share the code which you are using to save the data.

Comment: Please show us the content of your model class. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because proguard removes (obfuscation) unused code and renames classes and class members' (variables and methods) names to shorter names. There are two ways to keep them as you want

> **OPTION 1.** Add annotation before every field and between parentheses put what name you want to be displayed in Firebase.

***Method A)*** Add annotation to public fields

```
public class Datum {
    @PropertyName("name")
    public String name;
}
```

***Methods B)*** Add annotation to public `setter`/`getters` if your fields are private

```
public class Datum {

    private String name;

    @PropertyName("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @PropertyName("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

> ***OPTION 2.*** Configure proguard file to keep class, field and method names as is.

***Method A)*** Do it as per Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard). Add following lines to your proguard file. Below lines mean *names of every class member* (field, constructor and method) in `models` package and in sub-package of `models` direcotry will be kept as-is.

```
  # Add this global rule
    -keepattributes Signature

    # This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
    # the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
    # of your app.
    -keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** { *;}
```

***Method B)*** Adding classes one-by-one

If you want to keep name and class members of `User` class then add this.

```
-keep class com.josiah.app.data.models.User{ *;}
```

***Methods C)*** Add all classes in a package

Let's say all of your model classes are inside `models` package and you want to keep *names of all classes and class members* intact in that package. Then you have to add following line into your proguard file.

```
-keep class com.josiah.app.data.models.** { *;}
```

**NOTE:**

- `*` means everything inside class (fieds, methods and contructors)
- `**` after package means everything in this package (subpackages and classes)

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! I tried the first solution but it didn't work out, but the second solution worked, I know it's not very safe, but I will have to do it with all my model classes for the app to work.

Comment: If all of your model classes are in the same package you can use `-keep class com.josiah.app.data.models.** { public private *;}` instead. That will keep all classes and class members' names as-is. Check edited answer.